# Teleport Bug - (Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

With Roblox, I already tried 3-4 Times but this error still pops up:

> Zone4Tp is not a valid member of Workspace "Workspace" -  Client -
> LocalScript:3

And if you are wondering, yes it is in Workspace. Here is my Code:

```
local but = script.Parent
local localplayer = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local tppart = game:GetService("Workspace").Zone4Tp -- Replace with your TpPart name if you changed it.

but.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(plr)
    localplayer.Character:MoveTo(tppart.Position)
end)
```

When I test it it keeps spamming that it is not available for workspace. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
--workspace.StreamingEnabled=false
```